# How to delete repetitive lines of two rich text boxes?

Tags: c#, search, richtextbox, lines

I have 2 rich text boxes on the form containing thousands of URLs which have some in common. I mean there are some URLs that are included in both. There is only one link per line in every rich text box. I want to add another rich text box containing links which are not in common among those rich text boxes.

for example let RTB1 be like this:

```
link1

link2

link3

link4

link5
```

and RTB2 be like :

```
link1

link3

link4
```

now RTB3 must be like:

```
link2

link5
```

what is the code that deletes repetitive lines of two rich text boxes?

Comment: Have you made any effort to figure this out yourself before asking here?

Comment: I'll give you a hint, look at the LINQ methods. For the most part, they do what they are named.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
string[] links1 = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n');
string[] links2 = richTextBox2.Text.Split('\n');

string[] uniqueLinks = links1.Union(links2).Distinct().ToArray();
```